# How to call C# libraries from Excel?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, dll, add-in

I wrote C# libraries and I want to use libraries Objects through an Excel User Interface.

The User could select a Range and some buttons would run methods with selected range as input.

In Visual Studio, I've seen that I am able to write a C# Excel Add-In: is it the good way to do it ? Is there a better way ? Maybe create a C# Excel Template and write code in it ?

Any good tutorial / sample ?

Comment: Speaking about **Visual Studio**, what about [Create an Application-Level Add-In to Automate Common Office Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd935909.aspx) (MSDN) by *Robert Green* and [How to Create a Toolbar for an Excel Add-In](http://invertedindex.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/vsto-how-to-create-a-toolbar-for-an-excel-add-in/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to provide some additional functionality over and above the ones provided by Excel, it is best to create a Excel Add-in. If you want to provide the user with only a limited set of functionalities and need control over all the user actions, you need to create a C# application with the Excel object embedded in it (or use 3rd party excel libraries which provide easy APIs).